# Run blocking code on thread without blocking that thread

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, firebase-remote-config

I need to fetch an RemoteConfig from Google Firebase (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig#public-taskboolean-fetchandactivate) synchronously and block an main Android thread by that. I am using an Kotlin extensions to simplify implementation with coroutines (https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services/).

I tried this approach:

```kotlin
class MyApplication : Application() {

  lateinit var remoteConfig: FirebaseRemoteConfig  

  override fun onCreate() {
    runBlocking{
      remoteConfig = Firebase.remoteConfig
      remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate().await()
    }
    
    // ...other code, mainly DI init, what needs to be run AFTER remoteConfig is fetched.

  }
}
```

The problem with is approach is (I think) that I blocked the main thread and `fetchAndActivate()` is trying to run the task on that blocked thread. Result is an deadlock.

Is there any way of solving this? Maybe some kind of waiting, without actually blocking the thread?

I also tried to move everything into runBlocking block, but then Android thinks, that `onCreate()` was finished and launches main activity. I need to run this remote config fetch BEFORE allowing activity to start.

Comment: You can show SplashScreen during the data loading time. And after the data is loaded show the main activity.

Comment: If you move everything inside `runBlocking`, `onCreate` will not return until all those things are done. How can Android think it's done? Are you sure this result wasn't instead observed when trying other things (for instance a `GlobalScope.launch` or something like that?)

Comment: @Joffrey Thats the problem. runBlocking waits for `fetchAndActivate`, but this method launches task on same thread, I paused by runBlocking... And thats the reson of deadlock.

Comment: @Sergio Problem with that is, that dagger must be loaded at that point and dagger cannot be loaded without remoteconfig, because it is using it.

Comment: I don't use Dagger, but I think you need to use Providers to have asynchronously loaded dependncies.